# User creation in EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

While cloud-init is the optimal way to create users in an EC2 host at the time it gets instantiated I would like to hear how the community usually manages a dynamic group of users. I am planning to use Ansible to achieve the user config management but I am unsure how we can call the Ansible playbook from cloud-init script. Any pointers will be of help.

Comment: you could add the users before the ec2 is instantiated using a system such as packer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, cloud-init by nature runs once and only once per instance, at creation time. If you expect your list of users to change over time and you want to keep an instance up to date, cloud-init isn't going to cover that use case.

The `user` module in ansible can be a good way to manage system users throughout the lifecycle of an instance.

I can't speak for the entire community but one possibility would be to maintain a list of users in ansible and then run your playbook targeting the instance or instances when there is a change to the user list.

Rather than cloud-init, these `ansible-playbook` runs could be manually run by an operator, run at a regular time interval, or triggered to run automatically with a combination of version control and continuous delivery.